# How can i remove default rate in shipping method

Tags: magento-1.9, shipping-methods

I am created free shipping products configuration, Using by

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sNAm2KiYkwo

And result Look like,

[image]

How can i remove default ship by weight column.

Comment: Do you want to remove the "Ship by Weight" for ALL products or just specific products?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable other two shipping methods by disabling it from admin panel

In this case you should customize your checkout-onepage template file -> **app/ design/ frontend/ default/ YOURTEMPLATE/ template/ checkout/ onepage/ shipping_method/ available.phtml**

Put the following code right before the **dl** tag that displays the different options.

> if ( array_key_exists('freeshipping', $_shippingRateGroups )) {
>     unset($_shippingRateGroups["dummyship_name1"]);
>     unset($_shippingRateGroups["dummyship_name2"]); }

Hope this will help you

Comment: I need both shipping method options, free shipping is just for only 2 items, remaining items only based on matrix rate. How can i disable ??

Comment: free shipping is an optional, not for my all products

Comment: Check the answer again . cheers :)

Comment: there is no onepage folder you mentioned

Comment: This is exact location what you mentioned last, /app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping_method

Comment: not working....

Comment: please print the array and check the shipping methods available